# Function fails to bind to output parameter

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Azure Function with a `TimerTrigger` that does work and produces 400,000 Service Bus Topic messages. I'm currently using the Service Bus API to manually push messages into it within my Function. I'm now wanting to replace that code with an output binding instead, which simplifies things.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("ExportProcessor")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 30 5 */1 * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, 
        ILogger logger, 
        [ServiceBus("new-movie-publish", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)]IAsyncCollector<string> output)
    {
        await output.AddAsync("Foo");
        await output.AddAsync("Bar");
    }
}
```

The problem though is that when I run this test code, it fails with this error:

> MicrosoftAzure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'output' to type IAsyncCollector`1.
>   Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding.

When [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---usage), `IAsyncCollector`1` is a supported binding.

### Updated to show config files and dependencies.

This is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.0-beta4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.0-beta4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My host.json file:

```
{
  "logger": {
    "categoryFilter": {
      "defaultLevel": "Information",
      "categoryLevels": {
        "Host": "Information",
        "Function": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my local.settings.json config

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "...",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "...",
    "ExportUrl": "...",
    "ExportUtcHour": 5,
    "DefaultConnection": "...",
    "NewMovieTopic": "new-movie-publish",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "..."
  }
}
```

These settings work fine when I use this code to publish messages:

```
public class MoviePublisherConfig
{
    public MoviePublisherConfig()
    {
        this.AzureWebJobsServiceBus = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameof(AzureWebJobsServiceBus), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        this.NewMovieTopic= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameof(NewMovieTopic), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    }

    public string AzureWebJobsServiceBus { get; set; }
    public string NewMovieTopic { get; set; }
}

public class MoviePublisher
{
    private readonly MoviePublisherConfig config;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public MoviePublisher(MoviePublisherConfig config, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task PublishMovies(Movie[] movies)
    {
        var topicClient = new TopicClient(config.AzureWebJobsServiceBus, config.NewMovieTopic);
        var pendingTasks = new List<Task>();

        for(int index = 0; index < movies.Length; index++)
        {
            string movieJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movies[index]);
            byte[] messageBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(movieJson);
            var message = new Message(messageBuffer);

            Task sendTask = topicClient.SendAsync(message);
            pendingTasks.Add(sendTask);

            if (pendingTasks.Count >= 1000)
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(pendingTasks);
                this.logger.LogInformation($"Processed {pendingTasks.Count} new movies.");
                pendingTasks.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just tried your code, works like charm... Do you mind sharing dependencies and versions?

Comment: Updated to show my dependencies and configurations.

Comment: Ah, v2... I think Service Bus is not yet fully integrated in beta.

Comment: Are there work-arounds? This is the second tech I've tried to integrate with Service Bus. Has issues with NodeJs functions timing out, so moved to netstandard .net core.

Comment: Stick with v1/.NET full for now would be a safe bet

Comment: Publishing manually rather than using output bindings works. Would there be any downside to just leaving my code as-is then, and not using the output binding?

Comment: If you need to use ServiceBus in V2,  please update to our latest bits on myget(nuget feed: https://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2) version: 3.0.0-beta4-11250. We will be updating the official nuget packages soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (March 2018), Service Bus support on V2 of Functions is still "under construction". It's kind of there, but requires some magic to be applied.

The problem is that it was moved out of default package of bindings into extensions model, and that one is still rough.

See the following issues on github:

[Migrate ServiceBus Extension to .NET Core](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1329)  - closed, but see the comments

[Build failure after installing ExtensionsMetadatGenerator into empty v2 app](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/624)

The working version is not in NuGet yet, but if you really need, you can get it in [MyGet](http://myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2), version 3.0.0-beta4-11250.

Other options include sticking with manual sending, or using V1 / .NET Full version of Functions.